# End-loop condition to retrieve my mined smart contract using backlink?

Tags: solidity, web3js, blockchain

I want to retrieve all my smart contracts and interact with them, without the need of scanning over and over the blockchain.

In order to do that, I inspire myself about a simple but clever property of the blockchain: the backlink. I'm storing the address of my previous smart contract each time I'll deploying a new one:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.2;

contract Test {

    address public scAddress; //current address of the smart contract
    address public lastSCAddress; // address of the previous smart contract

}
```

So I'm creating my own smart contract chain inside the blockchain. My problem is when I want to retrieve it and interact with them: using web3.js:

```
function retrieveSmartcontract(lastKnownAddress) {
  for(var i = 0; i < (until it reaches the oldest one); i++) {
    var documentContract = web3.eth.contract(abiArray);
    var sc = documentContract.at(lastKnownAddress);
    var result = sc.getData.call();
    console.log('Data: '+ result)

    var newaddress = sc.getLastSCAddress().call();
    var sc[i] = documentContract.at(newaddress);
    var result[i] = sc2.getData.call();
    console.log('Data2: '+ result[i]);

}
})
```

Take it more as a pseudo-code. I will always know `lastKnownAddress`.
I don't know what is the ending condition for my loop. I thought about `contract.address == unfinied`, but I'm not sure about it.

Thank you for your valuable time and help.

**EDIT:** **Can It be solved by this?**

Since I do know the address of the last smart contract deployed, when I am initiate this process the last smart contract address is also equal to the "oldest" one. I just need to save it in an other smart contract.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.2;

contract Test {

   address public lastSCAddress; // address of the previous smart contract
   string name;

}
```

Here is the code of the new smart contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.2;

contract Test2 {

   address public lastSCAddress; // address of the last contract mined
     address public oldestSCAddress; // address of the first ever smart contract deployed
   string name;

}
```

Last, my code for the loop:

```
function retrieveSmartcontract(lastKnownAddress) { 
    // interacting with test2.sol

    var test2 = web3.eth.contract(abiArray);
    var sc = test2.at(lastKnownAddress);
    var oldestAddress = sc.getOldestSCAddress.call();
    var tmpAddress = lastKnownAddress;

  while(oldestAddress!== tmpAddress) {
    // interacting with test.sol

    var test = web3.eth.contract(abiArray);
    var sc2 = test.at(lastSCAddress);
    var result = sc2.getData.call();
    console.log('Data: '+ result)
    var tmp = sc2.getLastAddress.call();
    tmpAddress = tmp;
}
})
```

I hope I can use the while loop here. So basically, it will call the getLastAddress until `oldestAddress` does not match `tmpAddress`.

**Can someone confirm this please?**

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't it `contract.address == "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"`?

Comment: Maybe your answer is correct when I'm deploying my smart contracts on a new and fresh blockchain.

But let's imagine, I'm using the testnet network, I don't think it will be `"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"` since I'm joining an network which has already hundreds of blocks and smart contracts mined.
But when I wrote this answer to you , I had ans Idea, I'll edit my own post. Can you confirm me if this is going to work?

Comment: If your first contract has `address public lastSCAddress;` set to `0`, then the test I gave you is correct. Other contracts do not matter.

Comment: Please Have a look at my EDIT. I think it is basically the same thing. A confirmation will really help me. Thanks

Comment: When you deploy `Test` for the first time, what is the value of `lastSCAddress`?

Comment: Can it be himself?
Oohhh yeah, I see the which problem is coming. It will not enter in the loop, right?
Or maybe can I leave this variable as `null` ?

Comment: No. The first deployment of `Test` leaves `lastSCAddress` at `0`. That's the indication I was talking about in the answer.

Comment: Will it not interfere if other smart contracts are mined at `"0x0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"`?

Comment: You have a 10^-48 chance that this happens. So, no.

Comment: Just a last question: why so? 
And then I promise I stopped bothering you :)

Comment: An address is 20-bytes long, so 160 bits. So there are 2^160 addresses. But 2^10 = 1024 = ± 10^3. So 2^160 =± 10^48. So for a contract to be `0x000...` is 10^-48.